# Injecting Gitlab CI variables into Ansible

Tags: ansible, gitlab-ci

I am using Gitlab CI runners to execute Ansible playbooks and having trouble getting variables defined in Gitlab pushed into Ansible. I know I can use `lookup('env','var')` to get the variable, but that doesn't seem to work inside the yml inventory files. For example:

```
# List everything in vCenter
- ansible-inventory --list -i vSphere/vxrail.vmware.yml
```

vxrail.vmware.yml

```
plugin: vmware_vm_inventory
strict: False
hostname: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
username: administrator@vsphere.local
# This isn't working
password: lookup('env','vCenterAdminPass')
validate_certs: False
with_tags: True
```

How do I get variables passed in?

Answer (score 6):

Let use `--extra-vars` (or `-e`) to passing variables, see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line

Here below is a snippet showing how can I pass the extra vars into my Gitlab CI script section.

```
deploy_ec2:
  stage: deploy_ec2
  script:
    - ansible-playbook cuong-conf/main.yml --limit="${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}" -e "env=${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME} app=${CI_PROJECT_NAME} method=${CI_JOB_STAGE} app_path=${APPLICATION_PATH}"
  only:
    - staging
    - demo
    - production
  tags:
    - gitlab_runner
```

Answer (score 4):

Although I'm not quite sure lookups will work in an inventory plugin config file (I'll let your try), what you have written cannot work at all. You are literraly saying that the password is the string "lookup('env','vCenterAdminPass')".

The content of the password should be the result of the lookup which will be processed by jinja2. So you need to enclose your expression in a jinja2 template block:

```
password: "{{ lookup('env','vCenterAdminPass') }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a build job that injected the password into inventory file:

```
- 'echo "password: $vCenterAdminPass" >> vSphere/vxrail.vmware.yml'
```